# Como saber si existe la clave:valor que busco, prop y value dentro del obj

Tags: javascript

Tengo que hacer lo siguiente:

> Implementar la función objContains: debe buscar dentro de un objeto anidado un par {clave: valor}  especifico. Tanto el objeto como el nombre de la propiedad y su valor serán recibidos por parámetro.
> En el caso de que encuentre el valor indicado en cualquier nivel del objeto debe devolver true, de lo contrario, devolver false.
> Pista: utilizar typeof para determinar si el valor de una propiedad es un objeto para aplicar allí la recursión

mi problema es que me falta un solo test que pase y no encuentro el error:

× Debería devolver true si encuentra la propiedad y su valor correcto
√ Debería devolver false si NO encuentra la propiedad
√ Debería devolver false si encuentra la propiedad pero su valor es incorrecto
√ Debería devolver false si encuentra el valor pero no asociado a dicha propiedad

Me pasa esto por parámetro:

`var objContains = function(obj, prop, value)`

y mi código es este, pero no me funciona.

```
 for(let elemento in obj)
   if(typeof obj[elemento] === "object"){
     objContains(obj[elemento])
     if(obj[prop][value])
       return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  
}
    }
```

Comment: que querra decir que no te corren los test.... igual, ahi estas llamando a una funcion que tiene 3 parametros, con uno solo...

Comment: que no me estaria funcionando el codigo

Comment: Por favor, pon el código completo de tu función para ver cómo está declarada. Además, lo que dice gbianchi es correcto... En la llamada recursiva dentro de lo que supongo que es la función pasas únicamente un parámetro, y no el nombre de la propiedad y valor buscados

Comment: y como puedo acceder a buscar esa clave:valor que quiero ?

Comment: Pero.. tenes otros problemas antes... tu funcion recibe 3 parametros, solo mandas uno... tu funcion hace return inmediatamente la primera vez que un objeto es diferente al que buscas.. es lo que intentatabas? si explicas cada linea, donde estas recorriendo el objeto?

Answer (score -1):

La función la pintas de esta manera:

```
var objContains = function(obj, prop, value)
```

Y la llamas así:

```
objContains(obj[prop])
```

En todo caso podrías trabajar así:

```
var objContains = function(...obj)
```

Comment: Pero eso no es lo que pide el OP. Claramente la firma de la función debe ser la que se establece en la pregunta: *Tanto el objeto como el nombre de la propiedad y su valor serán recibidos por parámetro*. ¿Cómo tu respuesta soluciona el problema?